# How do I make the div to stay at the top when rotatingX

Tags: css

I have this:

```
div {
    transform:rotateX(120deg);
}
```

But when I make the transformation it leaves me a white space over the div. How can I make the div to stay at the top.

Comment: You may need to expand on your problem a bit more.. I'm sort of confused, and don't really know how to answer. There are ways to set a different transformation point for your rotating object, so that it rotates around that point rather than the center.. Is that what you need?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty sure you are looking for `transform-origin`.

Something like `transform-origin: 0% 33%;` works in your case.

[**jsFiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/Y5xRG/1/) - play around with it.

By default, the origin is set to `50% 50%`.

[**See MDN documentation.**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin)

Comment: Just a side note, demo won't work on firefox as prefixed version is used here, you should also use the standard property `transform-origin` and not just the prefixed ones, also, declare all prefixed version properties first and than the standard ones

Comment: @Mr.Alien Thanks - completely forgot about that. Fixing it right now.

Answer (score 2):

To change the rotation point of an element, you can use `transform-origin`.

Browser support is limited, and prefixed, so check in here for some more information:
(it will only work in chrome and safari for 3D transformations like this, I believe)

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform-origin.asp

Here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/zAZuY/1/

notice how the second div sticks to the top. Also, take note that a 120 degree rotation will begin to flip your element upside down if the origin point is at the top (you are actually seeing the backside of the element at this point)

Comment: True, though its a quicker read for lazy people ;) thanks though, I'll keep it in mind

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
div {
    transform:rotateX(120deg);
    transform-origin:top left;
}
```

Best way to grasp this is to pretend the DIV is a piece of paper and you're sticking a nail onto the top left hand side of the paper.  Now since you're flipping the paper on the X axis, it uses the top of the paper as the folding point and turns itself around that area.

Remember to declare both the "webkit" and "ms" versions of "transform" and "transform-origin" in your CSS since the vanilla statements haven't been universally adopted yet.